# Why is my deployed site referencing the local directory it was created in?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am deploying to IIS 6.0 and it has not been a simple task. I've finally managed to connect to the database (SQLServer 2005) but only as far as logging in (ASP.NET Membership). As soon as I try to click on another secure page the database connection automagically vanishes. This is a secondary concern.

Here is my error message:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5009598
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity) +341
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +129
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +270
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +123
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +166
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +115
   DataAccess.IntranetTableAdapters.user_in_rolesTableAdapter.GetUsersInRoles() in C:\Users\me\Dropbox\Projects\MS\customer\DataAccess\CustomerIntranet.Designer.cs:2407
   BusinessClasses.RoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) in C:\Users\me\Dropbox\Projects\MS\customer\BusinessClasses\RoleProvider.cs:86
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +182
   System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRule.IsTheUserInAnyRole(StringCollection roles, IPrincipal principal) +132
   System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRule.IsUserAllowed(IPrincipal user, String verb) +256
   System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationRuleCollection.IsUserAllowed(IPrincipal user, String verb) +201
   System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule.OnEnter(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs) +8886509
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

In particular I am looking at these two lines and wondering why my local machine directory paths are showing up in this error message which is deployed on a remote server.

```
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +115
   DataAccess.IntranetTableAdapters.user_in_rolesTableAdapter.GetUsersInRoles() in C:\Users\me\Dropbox\Projects\MS\customer\DataAccess\CustomerIntranet.Designer.cs:2407
   BusinessClasses.RoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) in C:\Users\me\Dropbox\Projects\MS\customer\BusinessClasses\RoleProvider.cs:86
```

Can someone please tell me from where or why these paths are being displayed? Just to reiterate, these paths are from my development machine where the app was created. The error message is being displayed on a remote server (via remote desktop connection).

Thanks

Comment: Is the database server accessible from the deployed location? This is more of an infrastructure issue than a programming problem. If the database connection string is "localhost" then is there an active SQL instance using standard ports on the deployed server. If not is the host name fully qualified and an entry that would be available for lookup on the DNS server used in your deployed location. Are there firewall rules restricting or blocking remote access? It's not clear if the membership provider uses the same connection string as the role provider - does the role provider need updating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the paths were coming from pdb files which I had copied to the remote server. I have just copied the whole application from my development machine for a quick test and these files were carried with it.

I did a search in notepad++ for the path strings and although it didn't actually return the strings, it returned the pdb file paths from within the project.

I deleted the pdb files from the server and now my error message doesnt display my local file paths.

```
SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5009598
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity) +341
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +129
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +270
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +195
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +232
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +185
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +33
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +524
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +66
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +479
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +123
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +166
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) +115
   DataAccess.CustomerIntranetTableAdapters.employeeTableAdapter.GetEmployeeByUserID(Nullable`1 id) +377
   BusinessClasses.GlobalOperations.getEmployeeByUserID(Guid id) +96
   Customer.EmployeeTimesheet.prepareComponents() +327
   Customer.EmployeeTimesheet.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +179
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Now I just need to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

> These kind of errors usually happen when the connectionString has a typo mistake. Check to see if everything is proper in your web.config file.